# How can I envoke <Link to=''> route transition from a custom function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an AntD table with clickable rows in a React functional component. I want to write a function which would change a route (link to a child component) similar to clicking on Go to somepath element. How can I do that?

```
<Table 
    dataSource={patientsInTable} 
    columns={columns} 
    onRow={(record, rowIndex) => { 
        return { onClick: (event) => {console.log('go'); return (<Redirect to='/dashboard' />)} }; 
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, I tried <Redirect>, however it doesn't work.  <Table 
                  dataSource={patientsInTable} 
                  columns={columns} 
                  onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
                    return {
                      onClick: (event) => {console.log('go'); return (<Redirect to='/dashboard' />)}
                    };
                  }}
                  />

Comment: Also, I tried window.location.href = '/somepath'. But it reloads the page, I think it is a wrong way to do that.

Comment: Instead of row, you can have a action column and on click of that column you can redirect - https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-chebyshev-ch2to. Check the columns, I have added anchor tag in render().

Comment: Thank you! It's OK, but driven usability goals I need a clickable row.

Comment: Hi Alexander, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional component, you can redirect to another component using,

```
props.history.push('/dashboard')
```

But to work with history object we need to wrap the component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
   return(
     <Table 
       dataSource={patientsInTable} 
       columns={columns} 
       onRow={(record, rowIndex) => { 
            return { onClick: (event) => {
                console.log('go'); 
                props.history.push('/dashboard');
             } 
          }; 
       }} 
     />
   )
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ollx6i)

Comment: ravibagul91, thank you for quick and clear answer! It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean programatically, try

```
this.props.history.push('/your-link')
```

Edit: Updated along with your code

```
<Table 
    dataSource={patientsInTable} 
    columns={columns} 
    onRow={(record, rowIndex) => { 
        return { onClick: (event) => {console.log('go'); this.props.history.push('/dashboard')} }; 
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! It will work in a class component. How can I adjust that to a functional component?